# WebView save and restore state issue with postUrl

Tags: android, android-webview, android-orientation, savestate

I am using the following components in my application

> - Activity
> - Fragment
> - WebView

**Goal** - I don't want to reload the webview on orientation change.

**Issue** - Currently I see the following error on orientation change "Webpage was not available. The webpage at https://fakeurls.org could not be loaded because net::ERR_CACHE_MISS"

**Steps to Reproduce**

- Application was opened in device portrait mode.
- Content of given URL was loaded in webview successfully
- Device was turned to landscape mode
- Webview shows error

**Code** - Android application makes a post request in a webview to url https://fakeurls.org. Below is the code for MyActivity and MyFragment class

**MyFragment.java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private String mUrl = null;
    private String mPostData = null;

    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MyFragment newInstance(@android.support.annotation.NonNull String url, String postData) {
        MyFragment MyFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("URL", url);
        bundle.putString("POSTDATA", postData);
        MyFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return MyFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        instantiateWebView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            if (args == null) {
                return;
            }
            mUrl = args.getString("URL");
            mPostData = args.getString("POSTDATA");
            mWebView.postUrl("https://fakeurls.org/", EncodingUtils.getBytes(mPostData, "BASE64"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mWebView != null) {
            mWebView.saveState(outState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mWebView.destroy();
    }

    private void instantiateWebView(View view) {
        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyFragment mMyFragment;

    @NonNull
    public static Intent createIntent(Context context, String url, String postData) {
        return new Intent(context, MyActivity.class).putExtra("URL", url)
        .putExtra("POSTDATA", postData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_link_viewer);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mMyFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_frame);
        if (mMyFragment == null) {
            final String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");
            final String postData = getIntent().getStringExtra("POSTDATA");
            mMyFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(url, postData);
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_frame, mMyFragment)
                    .commitNow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        mMyFragment.cancelTasks();
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue and not reload the webview but retain display on orientation change. Any help is appreciated.